# iOS Color Space iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, colors

I'm having big troubles using colors in iOS 10. My designer is working with Photoshop using sRGB Color Space that should be the same color space as Xcode 8. But we're having problems replicating the same colors. Look at the image : [image: screenshot]

This is a simulator screenshot. The orange line is an image, the orange box is a color taken from the image. This is the code :

```
UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage.init(named: "Orange 1 pixel")!)
```

Why the colors are different? How can we do?

**EDIT :**

This is the RGB I get using SIP color picker on Mac using the sRGB Color Space :

```
UIColor(red:233.0/255.0, green:89.0/255.0, blue:35.0/255.0, alpha:255.0/255.0)
```

The HEX is this : `#E95923`

The image is this, I stretched it because in the project I'm using at as 1x1 pixel :

[image]

Comment: Can you link the image and the RGB ?

Comment: @FedericoMalagoni done

Comment: Could it be related to translucency? Are you using the `UINavigationController`? If you have it in the storyboard, can you check your identity inspector for NavigationViewController / Navigation Bar and verify if "Translucent" is checked?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your image and your RGB. The color you write is not the same of your image.

This is the correct RGB :

```
UIColor(red:255.0 / 255.0, green: 97.0 / 255.0, blue: 41.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
```

On the top there are your image, in the bottom an `UIView`.

[image]

Comment: With photoshop color picker

Comment: But which color space you used?

Comment: sRGB IEC61966-2.1